# Solr range query for specefic id like /solr/select?q=x:[1,2,5,11,64589]

Tags: solr

I have some specific id like 1,2,5,11,64589 in solr (int type)

I want to qet query like ttp://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=x:[1,2,5,11,64589] but does not work (get error). how can do it ???

**Note:** i can implement with "**OR**" but i want simple way (and other problem limit in max url char length)

Comment: there seems to be no other way. what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are your options:

- `?q=x:(1 OR 2 OR 5 OR ...)`
- `?q=x:1 OR x:2 OR x:5 OR ...`
- `?q=x:(1 2 5 ...)` with [defaultOperator](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SchemaXml#SchemaXml-Defaultqueryparseroperator)="OR" (haven't tried this one but it should work)
- Write your own [RequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler)
- Write your own [QueryParser](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/22/exploring-query-parsers/)

Comment: @Hamid: Please do put what you used from the query patterns suggested by Mauricio.

Comment: Is there a way to use getByIds (real-time get) in solr repository? I face a similar issues where I want to retrieve multiple documents just by id alone and I see that realtime get is more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In Solr 4.10 and [Heliosearch 0.07](https://github.com/Heliosearch/heliosearch), you can use the more efficient terms query:

```
q={!terms f=id}1,2,5,11,64589
```

Comment: It looks like Heliosearch has been sunsetted. Their GitHub says that most of their changes got merged back into Solr core. This "terms query" syntax must have been part of that merge effort. I can confirm this works great in Solr 5.5.2.

Comment: Going to heliosearch website (linked from that github page) takes you to some malware installation page.  I guess the project is dead.