# How can I search on a list of values using Solr/Lucene?

Tags: lucene, solr

Given the following query:

```
(field:value1 OR field:value2 OR field:value3 OR ... OR field:value50)
```

Can this be broken down into something less verbose?  Basically I have hundreds of category IDs, and I need to search for items under large groups of category IDs (20-50 at a time).  In MySQL, I'd just use `field IN(value1, value2, value3)` rather than `(field = value1 OR field = value2 etc...)`.

Is there a simpler way for Solr/Lucene?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533815/solr-range-query-for-specefic-id-like-solr-selectqx1-2-5-11-64589

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use

```
field:(value1 value2 value3)
```

or if your default operator is AND then use

```
field:(value1 OR value2 OR value3)
```

Comment: Any idea where this is explained in the documentation?

Comment: While this approach works, it's not accurate. At least not in elastic. If you have any other field (in my case `_id`) with the same value, it will find those too.

ie: `/_search?q=(clientId:3966 OR 42952)` brings those 2 clients and another one with _id=42952

Comment: @NicolasMarianoObregon I'm not sure if this syntax should work in Elastic or not but you have made a typo when writing your query. `clientId:` should be outside of the parentheses.

Comment: Any tips on using this for rank instead of filtering on Solr?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but the following format did: `+(field:value1 OR field:value2 OR field:value3)`